# New Mongoose Schema `ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT` erorr in Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, nosql

## My Goal Is

If have find any data findOne() function update current endpoint with content, if not create a new element with Schema.

### Problem

If no data in db, so first `if` it throw me `ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT` with console.log = 1 but if have, all in well with console.log = 3.

```js
  try {
    const find = await endPointSchema.findOne({ uuid: uuid });
    if (!find) {
      const data = new endPointSchema({
        uuid: uuid,
        endpoint: [{ point: Endpoint, Content }],
        date: Date.now(),
      });
      await data.save();
      console.log(1);
      res.status(200).json({ message: "Succesfully Created new Breakpoint" });
      return;
    } else {
      if (!find.endpoint) {
        console.log(2);
        res.end();
        return;
      } else {
        console.log(3);
        res.end();
        return;
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    res.end();
    return;
  }
```

### My Endpoint

```js
route.post("/endpoint", AuthorizePanel, async (req, res) => {
  const { role, username, uuid } = req.user;
  if (!role && !username && !uuid) {
    res.sendStatus(401);
    return;
  }

  const { Endpoint, Content } = req.body;
  if (Endpoint === username) {
    res.status(403).json({ message: "Endpoint can not be same with your username!" });
    return;
  }

  try {
    const find = await endPointSchema.findOne({ uuid: uuid });
    if (!find) {
      const data = new endPointSchema({
        uuid: uuid,
        endpoint: [{ point: Endpoint, Content }],
        date: Date.now(),
      });
      await data.save();
      console.log(1);
      res.status(200).json({ message: "Succesfully Created new Breakpoint" });
      return;
    } else {
      if (!find.endpoint) {
        console.log(2);
        res.end();
        return;
      } else {
        console.log(3);
        res.end();
        return;
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    res.end();
    return;
  }
});
```

### authorizePanel

```js
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

export const AuthorizePanel = (req, res, next) => {
  const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;
  if (authHeader) {
    const token = authHeader.split(" ")[1];
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, (err, user) => {
      if (err) {
        res.sendStatus(403)
        return
      }
      req.user = user;
      next();
    });
  }
  next();
};
```

Comment: 1 is printed in the unsuccessful flow? And is the data saved?

Comment: yes thats interesting i know but after http header error I see its saved.

Comment: The error is typically when you are sending the res after one response is already sent. Looking at your code, I don't see how that is happening. Can you add/check more of your code flow where you are using res?

Comment: Like what I couldn't understand

Comment: Probably another res.end() or res.send() somewhere in this function before this.

Comment: ```js
  const { role, username, uuid } = req.user;
  if (!role && !username && !uuid) {
    res.sendStatus(401);
    return;
  }

  const { Endpoint, Content } = req.body;
  if (Endpoint === username) {
    res.status(403).json({ message: "Endpoint can not be same with your username!" });
    return;
  }
```

before functions looks like this

Comment: I meant for the same function. Is it inside this function too? Maybe you can edit the question to add in code.

Comment: I added my full function you can check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the auth middleware, if you look closely at the auth middleware you will notice a return statement in the jwt.verify function only returns for that function. After jwt.verify function executed the `next();` function works too. To interrupt that you need to add else block to your first if block

```js
export const AuthorizePanel = (req, res, next) => {
  const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;
  if (authHeader) {
    const token = authHeader.split(" ")[1];
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, (err, user) => {
      if (err) {
        res.sendStatus(403)
        return
      }
      req.user = user;
      next();
    });
  } else {
    next();
  }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

In authorizePanel, put your second next inside the else condition or remove it (if you want only authenticated users to move forward).
It is being called **every time**.

**Why I think there is an error**

To simplify let's call the function with mongoose call **function A**.

There is a callback in your JWT verify code, so that will be called asynchronously **at some point in the future**.

If the user has an authentication error then the request will attempt to return a response(asynchronously) and also call function A (immediately because of the next() outside if) which will send its own response.
Also if there is no error, then the flow will move to function A too. (Notice because of the other next() outside the if condition, the flow has already moved to A).

In any of these cases, there can be 2 responses sent by your server. One with JWT error and with your second **function A**. Or both from your **function A**.

The data might be saved but after that there will be an error because Headers are already sent and the server is attempting to do that again.

Comment: As I said I have used this middleware function but i have never get this error. I think the problem is in endpoint function, so you will ask me how you can be sure about that becouse when i replace this function another function dont get this error.

Comment: Does your other function also send response?